# Can i only change one pod in kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I only want to deploy one pod in k8s.

For example, I deploy several pods in one pool with the same codes, but I only want to change one pod to do some test. Can it be done？

Comment: The question itself is not very clear to me. May be you should consider sharing you `yml` template(s) as `deployment.yml` also, should neatly explain, what you desire from to be changed/updated ?

Comment: You probably mean can I deploy a new service or a new revision? Edit your question to be more specific on what you are trying to do, what you have tried, what the results were and any errors.

Comment: could be useful: https://github.com/ContainerSolutions/k8s-deployment-strategies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're describing in your question is actually the closest to what we call `Canary Deployment`.

In a nutshell `Canary Deployment` (also known as `Canary Release`) is a technique that allows you to reduce potential risk of introducing in production a new software version that may be corrupted. It is achieved by rolling out the change only to a small subset of servers ( in Kubernetes it may be just one pod ) before deploying it to the entire infrastructure and making it available to everybody.

If you decide e.g. to deploy one more pod using new image version and you've got already working deployment consisting let's say of 3 replicas, only 25 % of traffic will be routed to the new pod. Once you decide the test was successful you may continue rolling out the update to other pods.

[Here](https://medium.com/google-cloud/kubernetes-canary-deployments-for-mere-mortals-13728ce032fe) you can find an article describing in detail how you can perform such kind of deployment on Kubernetes.

It's actually similar approach to `Blue-Green Deployment` already mentioned by @Malathi and has a lot in common with it.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you meant `Blue-Green Deployments`.

The common release process involves, adding new pods with the latest release and perhaps expose a certain percent of the traffic to be routed to the new release pod. If everything goes well you can remove the old pods with old release and replace them with new pods with the new release.

This [article](https://medium.com/@jrhouston/orchestrating-blue-green-deployments-with-kubernetes-cb3632d19f87) talks of blue-green deployments with Kubernetes.

It is also possible to use service mesh-like [istio](https://thenewstack.io/tutorial-blue-green-deployments-with-kubernetes-and-istio/) with Kubernetes for advanced blue-green deployments such as redirect traffic to a new release based on header values or cookies.